# Apply copy transform constraint using script

Tags: scripting, rigging, constraints

I'll try writing this the best I can. I want to be able to apply a copy transform on Rig 1 so it can be controlled by Rig 2. Both rig has the same bone names etc. Instead of manually going to each bone and apply a copy transform constraint. I would like to be able to run a script or something where it does it automatically. Is this possible at all? I will do my best to help answer any questions or provide blend file if needed.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yAbTtWaeXYSN9i9qeyneAJo-C12S3cX3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is an example of how to do that, but I've left out three settings because I didn't know if the default was enough

```py
import bpy

src = bpy.data.objects['src']
dst = bpy.data.objects['dst']

for bone in dst.pose.bones:
    bone.constraints.new('COPY_TRANSFORMS')
    constraint = bone.constraints[-1]
    constraint.target = src
    constraint.subtarget = bone.name
```

You need to change the first two statements after the `import` to whatever code you need to select the two armatures.  I tested with two armatures that had obvious names.

I didn't set the Mix, Target Space, Owner Space, or influence, assuming the defaults were what you wanted.  They are the following fields `mix_mode`, `target_space`, `owner_space`, and `influence`.

mix mode can take any value in  this list: 'REPLACE', 'BEFORE_FULL', 'BEFORE', 'BEFORE_SPLIT', 'AFTER_FULL', 'AFTER', 'AFTER_SPLIT'.

The spaces can take any value in this list: 'WORLD', 'CUSTOM', 'POSE', 'LOCAL_WITH_PARENT', 'LOCAL', 'LOCAL_OWNER_ORIENT'

Influence is a floating point number in the range of 0.0 to 1.0

You can find out more about the meaning of the values in the [Copy Transforms Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_transforms.html) manual page.

Comment: I've added a link to a demo file, if you have the time to show how the script works on the demo file. That would be much appreciated. I'm new to scripting with little knowledge but tryin to learn.

Comment: @Andrew, in your demo file, remove the text in the text editor and paste my text in. in line 3 change the text string near the end (`'src'`) to `'Rig_1'`. In line 4 change the string (`'dst'`) to `'Rig_2'`.  Type ALT-P to run the script.

Comment: Dude you are the best. oh damn, I am greatly thankful. thank you very much.

Comment: @Andrew You're very welcome. Glad I could help.  Good luck with your Python.